# How add cell to UICollectionView programatically without storyBoard

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nib

I tried the follow code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Pictograma *pictograma;

    pictograma = [pictogramas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AddPictogramaCell *newCell = [[AddPictogramaCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) pictograma:pictograma];

    [newCell.nombre setText:pictograma.nombre];
    [newCell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pictograma.path]];

    newCell.pictograma = pictograma;

    return newCell;
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -
dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'
```

I don't use a storyBoard so I don't know how to tackle this.

Comment: do you wants to load custom CollectionCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things wrong here.

Firstly when you create your `collectionView` you need to add this line

```
[collectionView registerClass:[AddPictogramaCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];
```

Then in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you create your cell like this:

```
AddPictogramaCell *newCell = (AddPictogramaCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: As for now, the method is registerClass, and not more registerForClass

Answer (score 0):

To register a cell for reuse in Swift, you would do the following when creating your CollectionView:

```
collectionView.registerClass(AddPictogramaCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER")
```

Then when getting your cell, you would have something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell:AddPictogramaCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddPictogramaCell

  return cell
}
```